# tkz defpoint in multiple diagrams

Tags: tkz-euclide

If I want to use

```
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
```

On multiple tkz diagrams is there a way to put this in the preamble, maybe using a '\newcommand' type thing,  to save me reusing the same code in each separate diagrams within the same document.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
Un

% Proposition environment
\newenvironment{proposition}
{\begin{center}\em}
{\end{center}}
%Diagram environment
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\stepcounter{CountDiag}\vspace*{10pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}}
    {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\par Diagram~\theCountDiag
\end{center}}
%Step environment
\newenvironment{step}
{\stepcounter{CountStep}\vspace*{10pt} Step~\theCountStep\par
{\raggedright}}

\newcounter{CountStep} 
\newcounter{CountDiag}

%Reset counters   
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\setcounter{CountStep}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\setcounter{CountDiag}{0}} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{diagram}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(1.25,0.3){B} 
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\end{diagram}

\begin{step}
From postulate 2 we can set the compasses to the length of the         line $AB$ and setting the point at $A$ and draw a circle, with         radius $AB$, then repeat from $B$.
\end{step}


\begin{diagram}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B} 
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
    \tkzDrawCircles(A,B B,A)
\end{diagram}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example we can compile. You could create a custom environment, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two figures in the same document, the nodes in the first figure are always defined in the second. Sometimes it’s a problem.
You have several possibilities.
You can save a part of your code in an external file or a command. With a command you can add parameters if you want to keep the names but change the values.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newcommand{\preamble}[2]{%
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(#1,#2){B} 
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\preamble{3}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\preamble{1.25}{0.3}
\tkzDrawCircles(A,B B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.